# How to find by and delete an item in a mongoose array

Tags: javascript, mongoose

So I have the following:

```js
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PhotoSchema = new Schema({
  filename: { type: String, required: true },
  userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
  isPublic: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Boolean, default: false }
}, { timestamps: true });

const PhotoAlbumSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
  photos: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Array }
}, { timestamps: true });
```

My scenario is this: when I delete a Photo, I want to also delete it in the PhotoAlbum that contains it in photos.  What sort of query would I write to do this?

Comment: which type of the element in photos array?

Comment: the type is Photo in the photos array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$pull` in mongodb to do it.

Example:

```
let deleted_photo = await Photo.findOneAndDelete(your_condition);
await PhotoAlbum.updateMany({}, { $pull: {photos: deleted_photo } });
// or
await PhotoAlbum.updateMany({}, { $pull: {photos: {"_id" : deleted_photo._id } } });
```

Comment: For some reason, neither of those are working for me.  Am I missing something in any of my schemas perhpaps?

Comment: try changing `photos: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Array }` to `photos: { type: [PhotoSchema] }`

Comment: I get the error ```TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `model` is not a valid type within the array `photos`.```

Comment: that's strange because refer to your code, `PhotoSchema` is not a model

Comment: I had to export my PhotoSchema, because my default export was the Photo model.  Thank you very much.  That worked!